# OpenGl view matrix - wrong "camera" orientation and position

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera

The symptom is, that the "position of the camera" seems to be mirrored around the x axis (negative z instead of positive z) and the "orientation of the camera" is opposing to the expected.
 In other words, I have to rotate the camera by 180 degrees and move it forwards to see any renderings.
In all OpenGl camera tutorials which I have seen, there was always a positive z coordinate for the camera position. Maybe there is only a single sign mistake in the code, but I do not see it. I am also posting the corresponding shader code.
 My objects are rendered at world coordinate z=0.1.

The initialization of the camera instance is show in the following lines

```
m_viewMatrix = math::Matrix4D::lookAt(m_cameraPosition, m_cameraPosition + m_cameraForward, m_cameraUp);
```

where

```
m_cameraForward(math::Vector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)),
m_cameraRight(math::Vector3D (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)),
m_cameraUp(math::Vector3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)),
m_cameraPosition(math::Vector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f))
```

The result is a black screen. When I change the camera position to 
    m_cameraPosition(math::Vector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f)
everything works fine.

The function lookAt is given by the following lines:

```
Matrix4D Matrix4D::lookAt(
        const Vector3D& f_cameraPosition_r,
        const Vector3D& f_targetPosition_r,
        const Vector3D& f_upDirection_r)

    {
        const math::Vector3D l_forwardDirection = (f_targetPosition_r - f_cameraPosition_r).normalized();

        const math::Vector3D l_rightDirection = f_upDirection_r.cross(l_forwardDirection).normalized();
        const math::Vector3D l_upDirection = l_forwardDirection.cross(l_rightDirection); // is normalized
        return math::Matrix4D(
            l_rightDirection.x, l_rightDirection.y, l_rightDirection.z, l_rightDirection.dot(f_cameraPosition_r*(-1.0f)),
            l_upDirection.x, l_upDirection.y, l_upDirection.z, l_upDirection.dot(f_cameraPosition_r*(-1.0f)),
            l_forwardDirection.x, l_forwardDirection.y, l_forwardDirection.z, l_forwardDirection.dot(f_cameraPosition_r*(-1.0f)),
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
            );
    }
```

The memory layout of the matrix4d is column major, as expected by OpenGl.
All other functions like dot and cross are unit tested.

vertex shader:

```
#version 430

in layout (location = 0) vec3 position;
in layout (location = 1) vec4 color;
in layout (location = 2) vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix; // projection matrix
uniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0); // view matrix <------
uniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0); // model matrix

out vec4 colorOut;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * vw_matrix * ml_matrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    colorOut = color;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 430

out vec4 color;
in vec4 colorOut;

void main()
{
    color = colorOut;
}
```

edit (added perspective matrix):

```
Matrix4D Matrix4D::perspectiveProjection(
        const float f_viewportWidth_f,
        const float f_viewportHeight_f,
        const float f_nearPlaneDistance_f,
        const float f_farPlaneDistance_f,
        const float f_radFieldOfViewY_f)
    {
        const float l_aspectRatio_f = f_viewportWidth_f / f_viewportHeight_f;
        const float l_tanHalfFovy_f = tan(f_radFieldOfViewY_f * 0.5);
        const float l_frustumLength = f_farPlaneDistance_f - f_nearPlaneDistance_f;
        const float l_scaleX = 1.0f / (l_aspectRatio_f * l_tanHalfFovy_f);
        const float l_scaleY = 1.0f / l_tanHalfFovy_f;
        const float l_scaleZ = - (f_farPlaneDistance_f + f_nearPlaneDistance_f) / l_frustumLength;
        const float l_value32 = -(2.0f*f_farPlaneDistance_f*f_nearPlaneDistance_f) / l_frustumLength;

        return Matrix4D(
            l_scaleX,   +0.0f,      +0.0f,      +0.0f,
            +0.0f,      l_scaleY,   +0.0f,      +0.0f,
            +0.0f,      +0.0f,      l_scaleZ,   l_value32,
            +0.0f,      +0.0f,      -1.0f,      +0.0f);
```

Comment: Can we see your projection matrices, too? There are some conventions for the eye space, and you can define them as you like, but you have to be consistent about them. In classic GL, eye space is defined left-handed, with the camera looking at -z direction. And the projection matrix takes that into account and flips to right-handed coordinate space. In the general case, the projection matrix also decides on the viewing direction (and even the position, if you want to look at things that way, although nobody defines an eye space where the camera is not at origin, but it would work).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added the perspective matrix (which I use in my examples). the field of view is given in radians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your projection matrix is following the "classic" OpenGL conventions: viewing direction is (0,0,-1) in eye space (last row of the matrix).

However, your view matrix does not follow that convention: You must put the *negated* forward direction into the matrix (also for calculation the translation z component there). In its current form, the view matrix just rotates so that the forward direction is mapped to +z.

Negating this of course means that you will use a right-handed coordinate system for world space (which is what classic GL did). If you don't want that, you can also just change the projection matrix to actually look at +z.